# tkinter: how to align a set of radio buttons that differs in text length

Tags: python, tkinter

```
tech_radioButton1 = ttk.Radiobutton(selection_frame_1, text="ANT+", variable = self.tech_var, value = 1, command = self.tech_select)
tech_radioButton1.pack(side = 'top')
tech_radioButton2 = ttk.Radiobutton(selection_frame_1, text="Bluetooth", variable = self.tech_var, value = 2, command = self.tech_select)
tech_radioButton2.pack(side = 'top')
tech_radioButton3 = ttk.Radiobutton(selection_frame_1, text="BTLE", variable = self.tech_var, value = 3, command = self.tech_select)
tech_radioButton3.pack(side = 'top')
tech_radioButton4 = ttk.Radiobutton(selection_frame_1, text="WLAN", variable = self.tech_var, value = 4, command = self.tech_select)
tech_radioButton4.pack(side = 'top')
tech_radioButton5 = ttk.Radiobutton(selection_frame_1, text="UNII", variable = self.tech_var, value = 5, command = self.tech_select)
tech_radioButton5.pack(side = 'top')
```

I have this section of code for a set of radio button in my project, and it looks like this when I run it:

[image]

I would like to anchor them all to the west so their left side would be align vertically. I tried to use tk instead of ttk(since there is no anchor option in ttk) radiobutton and set anchor = 'w', but they still looks like this:
[image]

Could some one please help? TIA

Answer (score 3):

never mind, I found it out. I should have done anchor = 'w' when packing. So something like:

```
tech_radioButton1 = ttk.Radiobutton(selection_frame_1, text="ANT+", variable = self.tech_var, value = 1, command = self.tech_select)
tech_radioButton1.pack(side = 'top', anchor = 'w')
tech_radioButton2 = ttk.Radiobutton(selection_frame_1, text="Bluetooth", variable = self.tech_var, value = 2, command = self.tech_select)
tech_radioButton2.pack(side = 'top', anchor = 'w')
tech_radioButton3 = ttk.Radiobutton(selection_frame_1, text="BTLE", variable = self.tech_var, value = 3, command = self.tech_select)
tech_radioButton3.pack(side = 'top', anchor = 'w')
tech_radioButton4 = ttk.Radiobutton(selection_frame_1, text="WLAN", variable = self.tech_var, value = 4, command = self.tech_select)
tech_radioButton4.pack(side = 'top', anchor = 'w')
tech_radioButton5 = ttk.Radiobutton(selection_frame_1, text="UNII", variable = self.tech_var, value = 5, command = self.tech_select)
tech_radioButton5.pack(side = 'top', anchor = 'w')
```