# How do I align the radiobuttons to left in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmuJg.png)

My code shows the `radiobuttons` unaligned , tap picture to see, and I want to define `var(1,2,3,4,5)` in some better way.

I am very new to programming but I have tried using `.pack()`, `side`,`anchor` and `justify`.

```
var1 = tk.StringVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()
var3 = tk.StringVar()
var4 = tk.StringVar()
var5 = tk.StringVar()
var6 = tk.StringVar()
var7 = tk.StringVar()
var8 = tk.StringVar()

v = StringVar() 
rbutton=Radiobutton(tab2, text="ggdsh", variable=var1, value="1",width=15,justify=LEFT).grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=W)
rbutton2=Radiobutton(tab2, text="fjkhslafjksh", variable=var2, value="1",width=15,justify=LEFT).grid(column=0,row=2)
rbutton3=Radiobutton(tab2, text="sdjklfhsdfj", variable=var3, value="1",width=15,justify=LEFT).grid(column=0,row=3)
rbutton4=Radiobutton(tab2, text="skjlskhsdlgkjshgklsd", variable=var4, value="1",width=15,justify=LEFT).grid(column=0,row=4)
rbutton5=Radiobutton(tab2, text="sajfkshldjfhlsf", variable=var5, value="1",width=15,justify=LEFT).grid(column=0,row=5)
rbutton6=Radiobutton(tab2, text="sdfkj;kjfdlgh", variable=var6, value="1",width=15,justify=LEFT).grid(column=0,row=6)
rbutton7=Radiobutton(tab2, text="dsfjhkldsghsdghgfdsgdg", variable=var7, value="1",width=15,justify=LEFT).grid(column=0,row=7)
rbutton8=Radiobutton(tab2, text="gsjhdgjkdshl", variable=var8, value="1",width=15,justify=LEFT).grid(column=0,row=8)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter: how to align a set of radio buttons that differs in text length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789073/tkinter-how-to-align-a-set-of-radio-buttons-that-differs-in-text-length)

Answer (score 4):

Just use `.pack(anchor=W)`

```
Radiobutton(master=frame,text='Easy',padx = 20,variable=level,value=0,command=lambda : self.settings.setLevel(level.get())).pack(anchor=W)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loops for all things that repeat.
They will create the buttons for you in just a few lines of code.
A screenshot would have been nice. It's hard for me to grasp what you are trying to accomplish.

Thats how you would position a lable on the left side with pack:

```
w = Label(root, text="Blue", bg="blue", fg="white")
w.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Using Grid you would put them in the first column

Comment: The thing is when i try to execute this in a window, the buttons appear on the left but button dots in all the buttons don't allign. I'll post a picture soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
rbutton=Radiobutton(tab2, text="ggdsh", variable=var1, value="1").grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=tk.W)
```

This does the job for me. turns out the problem was specifying the `radiobutton` width and mixing `.pack()` and `.grid()` in my application.

Answer (score 0):

```py
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.title("Radio Button")
colorVar = StringVar()
colorVar.set('#FF0000')
bgColors = [("blue", '#0000FF'),("red", '#FF0000'),("yellow", '#FFFF00'),("cyan", '#00FFFF'),("gray", "#888888")]
frame = Frame(root, width=30, height=70)
frame.pack()
for text, color in bgColors:
    Radiobutton(frame, text=text, variable=colorVar, value=color).pack(anchor=W)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to define var(1,2,3,4,5) in some better way.

No need to add the `Radiobutton` parameter `width=15`, `justify=LEFT`

Easier way to use iterating to reduce widgets, items. and `StringVar`.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


tab2 = tk.Tk()
 
v = tk.StringVar(tab2, "1")
 
# Dictionary to create multiple buttons
values = {"ggdsh" : "1",
          "fjkhslafjksh" : "2",
          "sdjklfhsdfj" : "3",
          "sajfkshldjfhlsf" : "4",
          "sdfkj;kjfdlgh": "5",
          "dsfjhkldsghsdghgfdsgdg": "6",
          "gsjhdgjkdshl": "7"}

for (text, value) in values.items():
    tk.Radiobutton(tab2, text=text, variable=v,
                   value=value).grid(column=0, row=value, sticky=tk.W)

tab2.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
val_options = [
    "val1",
    "val2",
    "val3",
    "val4",
    "val5",
    "val6",
    "val7",
    "val8",
]

val_var = tk.StringVar()

for idx, val_option in enumerate(val_options):
    tk.Radiobutton(root, text=val_option, variable=val_var, value=val_option).grid(row=idx + 1, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).